# NodeJs unable catch the data post from ReactJs form

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I using ReactJs build the form for user key in the details. I also using NodeJs to handle the post data from the React. But the NodeJs seem like did not catched the data.

This is react event handling

```
handleSave(e){
        let caseData=this.state.caseInfo
        let url = 'http://localhost:8080'
        console.log(caseData)
            fetch(url,{
                method:"POST",
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                  },
                data: JSON.stringify({caseInfo: caseData}),
            })

          }
```

This is NodeJS

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
http.createServer(function(req,res){

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use(function (req, res){
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
        res.write('you posted:\n')
        res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
        console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    })

}).listen(8080);
```

I expect the data from the React can using post method to the Node and display the data in console log. However in the console of the server it display nothing.

Comment: Why are you using both `http` *and* `express`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're not using express in the standard way. I'd change it to be more like the following...

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ posted: req.body });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
});

app.listen(8080);
```

And probably just get rid of the call to `http.createServer` altogether.

--

Check out the docs for more routing examples: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After I remove the http now it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are serving your react app from another server, for instance `localhost:3000` (as used by create react app), and you are trying to make api calls to a server on `localhost:8080` you are going to get CORS errors because the browser sees these as two different domains. To get started, you can look at the docs here: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

But you will probably have to `npm install cors` where your server lives and use something like the following:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ posted: req.body });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
});

app.listen(8080);
```